# Remove duplicates after altering items

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script to clean urls to get base domains from example.com/example1 and example.com/example2 down to example.com My issue is when it goes to through the file of urls it will have duplicate base domains. I want to remove the duplicates while printing the urls to a file. below is the code I currently have.

```
enter from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import re

def main():

        fileOpen = Tk()
        fileOpen.withdraw() #hiding tkinter window

        file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Open file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt")])

        if file_path != "":
            print "you chose file with path:", file_path

        else:
            print "you didn't open anything!"

        fin = open(file_path)
        fout = open("URL Cleaned.txt", "wt")
        for line in fin.readlines():
                editor = (line.replace('[.]', '.')
                .replace('[dot]', '.')
                .replace('hxxp://www.', '')
                .replace('hxxps://www.', '')
                .replace('hxxps://', '')
                .replace('hxxp://', '')
                .replace('www.', '')
                .replace('http://www.', '')
                .replace('https://www.', '')
                .replace('https://', '')
                .replace('http://', ''))
                editor = re.sub(r'/.*', '', editor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Any help is appreciated. I have scoured the posts and tried all of the suggestions for my issue and have not found one that works.

Comment: usually, removing duplicate is done by creating a `set` from a `list`, since `set`s don't contain duplicates.

Comment: but I don't see where the url list is in your code. do you want to print `editor` to a file if it has not already been added?

Comment: I have used set but it only goes through and removes characters. and yes i want to  print editor to fout and the list of urls comes from a separate text file. The file contains one url per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expresion to find the base domains.

If you have one url per line in your file:

```
import re

def main():
    file = open("url.txt",'r')

    domains = set()
    # will works for any web like https://www.domain.com/something/somethingmore... , also without www, without https or just for www.domain.org
    matcher= re.compile("(h..ps?://)?(?P<domain>(www\.)?[^/]*)/?.*") 

    for line in file:
        # make here any replace you need with obfuscated urls like: line = line.replace('[.]','.')
        if line[-1] == '\n': # remove "\n" from end of line if present
            line = line[0:-1]
        match = matcher.search(line)
        if match != None: # If a url has been found
            domains.add(match.group('domain'))

    print domains

    file.close()

main()
```

For example, with this [file](http://pastebin.com/tpcdpmhB), it will print:

```
set(['platinum-shakers.net', 'wmi.ns01.us', 'adservice.no-ip.org', 'samczeruno.pl', 'java.ns1.name', 'microsoft.dhcp.biz', 'ids.us01.us', 'devsite.quostar.com', 'orlandmart.com'])
```

Comment: For some reason it is throwing an error of   File "URL Cleaner/Cleaner2.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "URL Cleaner/Cleaner2.py", line 27, in main
    domains.add(matcher.search(line).group('domain'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I just edited my answer, that code is working for me with python2.7

Comment: but it can't be with line `domains.add(matcher.search(line).group('domain'))` as it is no more in my code

Comment: you may have deleted it, but it appears OP hasn't if he still gets that error

Comment: I used updated code and it works but now with this the issue is the obfuscations in the urls are still present where there might be a [.] and not . I am trying to clean that out from this codes output. thanks for the help.

Comment: You can make some `replace` before calling `matcher.search` so you change obfuscations to original characters

Comment: I was able to do the replace but I am not able to do the re.sub to remove anything after .com/

Comment: What you mean with *remove anything after .com/*? Can you give an example of an url whose domain is not correct found with the regex I wrote?

Comment: here is the list of urls im testing on [link](http://pastebin.com/8hphma7k) and this is the output I get after the replaces. [link](http://pastebin.com/utwWiAH4)

Comment: I updated my answer again. Previous regex doesn't recognize subdomains, the new one does. I also write the result I'm getting with your replaced-file

Comment: awesome looks good but the next issue i see is that it has added a couple domains together thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The idea of the regex is to get as domain everything before the first `/` (ignoring http:// or http:// if present). If you need later to split subdomains also, you can use the `split()` method from string

Comment: 'devsite.quostar.complatinum-shakers.net' should be 2 domains and the devsite is a duplicate domain. this is what I was referring to.

Comment: Ok, I see, the problem is not the regex, is that in the file you sent me, the last line is `devsite.quostar.complatinum-shakers.net/99/web/config/index.php` and it should be two different lines: `devsite.quostar.com` and `platinum-shakers.net/99/web/config/index.php`. Is that correct?

Comment: Answer updated with my file and the result that the script prints

Comment: ok sorry for the late reply this works great for removing the duplicates and cleaning the urls now my last issue is i need it to print into a file with one url per line if i am missing something obvious sorry. I am still new to python and trying to come up with things to code.

Comment: A `set()` is like a list, you just need to iterate with for and print in a open file with `file.write(elementtowrite)`

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't seem to work but I will work with it and make sure I am not doing something wrong again thanks for your help. I need to learn more about regex. You have been very helpful and patient. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a python interpreter at the moment, but it should be something like: `for i in domains: filetooutput.write(i)` and the file should be opened with `filetooutput = open('urloutput.txt','w')`. Take care with indentation (I can make that correct in a comment) and don't forget to close your file at the end. If you still have problems, comment here and I will update my answer when having a python interpreter to write only working code

Comment: Thanks that is how I have it printing to a file but I did get it working with 'for i in domains:' 'fileout.write(i + "\n")' and that seems to have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use a regular expression:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r".*\.com/(.*)") # to get for instance 'example1' or 'example2' etc.

with open(file_path) as fin, open("URL Cleaned.txt", "wt") as fout:
    lines = fin.readlines():
    bases = set(re.search(p, line).groups()[0] for line in lines if len(line) > 1) 
    for b in bases:
        fout.write(b)
```

Using `with open(..)` auto closes the files after the executing the block of code

**Output:**

Using a text file with:

```
www.example.com/example1
www.example.com/example2
# blank lines are accounted for
www.example.com/example3

www.example.com/example4 
www.example.com/example4 # as are duplicates
```

as the lines, I got the output,

```
example1
example2
example3
example4
```

Comment: domains.add(matcher.search(line).group('domain')) - that line is from the other answer and is nothing to do with your original code or my answer

Comment: Pasted correct error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/URL Cleaner/Cleaner2.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "/URL Cleaner/Cleaner2.py", line 28, in main
    base = re.search(p, line).groups()[0] # base would equal for example 'example1'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'